# AJAX function to get JSON data

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I made a script to get JSON data from a file on our server using AJAX but I'm having trouble putting it into a function.

Here's my code:

```
function getJSON (file)
    {
      var request = AjaxRequest();
      var json = "";
      request.onreadystatechange = function ()
      {
         if(request.readyState==4 && request.status==200)
            {
              json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            }
      }
      request.open("GET", file, false);
      request.send();
      return json;
     }
```

The function does everything I want it to but I've been told to NEVER pass false to the AJAX request because of blocking. Something just seems wrong about this function but I have no idea how to change it. Should I change it? If so, how?

Comment: are you aware that if you used jquery you could do the above script with 1 line? just a tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't return it like this, it's an asynchronous operation, meaning your `json = JSON.parse(request.responseText)` happens *later*, when the server responds with data...long after you returned..  Instead you can pass in a function which accepts the data, like this:

```
function getJSON (file, callback)
{
  var request = AjaxRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function ()
  {
     if(request.readyState==4 && request.status==200)
     {
       callback(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
     }
  }
  request.open("GET", file, false);
  request.send();
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
getJSON("something.json", function(data) { 
  //use data, your json object/data
});
```

This way you're using the data when it's available, passing it onto the next function...this is the way asynchronous calls are intended to behave.

Comment: Nick, this piece of information has saved me a sh*t load of time and for that I am thankful. Somebody give this man a raise.